# IndexError: string index out of range, pyserial tkinter, python 3.4

Tags: python, string, while-loop, tkinter, pyserial

I am trying to change the color of a label once my serial port identify **@* or **`*

this is my code

```
while set_ser.isOpen():
 time.sleep(0.0001)
 bytess = set_ser.inWaiting()
 bytes = set_ser.read(bytess)
 get_serial = str(bytes.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
 loop.set(get_serial)

 if (get_serial[2]=='@'): #busy
     sLabelRead.configure(bg = 'red', fg='white')
     sLabelRead.place(x=10,y=600)
     mGui.update()
 elif (get_serial[2]=='`'): #ready:
     sLabelRead.configure(bg = 'orange', fg='black')
     sLabelRead.place(x=10,y=600)
     mGui.update()
 elif (get_serial==''): #none:
     sLabelRead.configure(bg = 'black', fg='white')
     sLabelRead.place(x=10,y=600)
     mGui.update()
 mGui.update()
else:
 print (get_serial)
 mGui.update()
```

but I am getting this error

```
if (get_serial[1]=='@'): #busy
IndexError: string index out of range
```

can somebody help me
thanks

Comment: That means that your string is smaller than 2 characters. You are probably getting an empty string, just check by yourself with a `print` or/and `len`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed my string was smaller than 2 characters. so I just checked the lengh of it and modify my conditionals, thanks, I was not getting all the time 2 or 3 elements, sometimes there was only 1 or nothing